# Bootstrap carousel to show custom taxonomy instead of custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a loop for showing custom post type, from custom fields into a Bootstrap Carousel with indicators. The thing is, the custom post type has 2 categories(custom taxonomies company_testimonial and agent_testimonial) of which i want to show only one.

I am already lost

```
<?php
$post_objects_testimonials = get_field('choose_testimonials');
if ($post_objects_testimonials):
?>
<!-- Section testimonials -->
<section class="testimonials">
<div class="container">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<?php
    $count = count($post_objects_testimonials);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
?>
<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php

    echo $i;

--------

?>" <?php
        if ($i == 0) {
?>
<div class="active">
<?php
        }
?>
</li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
    $count = 0;
?>
<?php
    foreach ($post_objects_testimonials as $post):
?>
<?php
        foreach ($post_objects_testimonials as $post):
?>
<?php
            setup_postdata($post);
            $test_image     = get_field('test_image');
            $test_image_url = $test_image['url'];
            $test_image_alt = $test_image['alt'];
?>
<div class="carousel-item
<?php
            if ($count == 0) {
                echo ' active';
            }
?>">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-11 mx-auto">
        <?php
            if (get_field('description')):
?>
<p class="quote-paragraph">
<?php
                the_field('description');
?>
</p>
<?php
            endif;
?>
<?php
            if (get_field('description') && get_field('job_title') && get_field('name')):
?>
<p class="quote-author">
<strong><?php
                the_field('name');
?></strong>
<?php
                the_field('job_title');
?>
<?php
                the_field('company');
?>
</p>
<?php
            endif;
?>
</div>
<?php
            $count++;
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
        endforeach;
?>
</div>
<div class="arrow-icons">
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<?php
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

I expect to show taxonomy company_testimonial but ignore agent_testimonial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the Advanced Custom Fields to hold the content that is stored in 'choose_testimonials'. Based on what I can see here, I would assume that settings inside of Advanced Custom Fields for that particular field are not correct.

If this is not the case, the wrapper or WordPress template you're using are not correct. We would need some more information regarding these things to help!